# QueryOver in NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I'm lost when it comes to to QueryOver in NHibernate, I'm trying to query over a database and retrive 4 values of importans, the rest are unnecessary and take up processing power.

I'm trying this:

```
var ext = _session.QueryOver<ExternServiceSettings>()
          .Where(x => x.ExternService == ExternServiceEnum.Outlook).List();
```

which works fine but takes too long and returns everything in the database. then I tried:

```
    var ext = _session.QueryOver<ExternServiceSettings>()
                  .Where(x => x.ExternService == ExternServiceEnum.Outlook)
                  .List<ExternServiceSettings>()
                  .Select(y => y.UserName);
```

However this only return the username and won't let me fetch more than one value...

All help is appreciated!

Comment: in the database I have alot of rows for different values, I would like to return 4 values and put them into a list, the operation above only works for fetching one of those 4. excuse my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should use `.SelectList()`

Check the example from doc:

```
var selection =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>()
        .SelectList(list => list
            .Select(c => c.Name)
            .SelectAvg(c => c.Age))
        .List<object[]>();
```

see more here:

### [16.7. Projections](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections)

Comment: I need to do the "x.ExternService == ExternServiceEnum.Outlook" check since i have other services in the same file and the values i want to return are in 4 different rows, does SelectList work either way?